# Condtional probability problem for machine learning

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I found this problem in a book (relates to ML, $F_1$ and $F_2$ are supposed to be features and $C$ is supposed to be label)

Given:

- $P(F_1=T \mid C=T) = 0.8$
- $P(F_1=T \mid C=F) = 0.9$
- $P(F_2=T \mid C=T) = 0.4$
- $P(F_2=F \mid C=F) = 0.6$
- $P(C=T) = 0.4$
- Assume $F_1$, $F_2$ are independent

What is $P(C=T \mid F_1=T, F_2=T)$?

The answer should be $0.2831$ but I'm not sure how to arrive here. I know that $$P(C=T \mid F_1=T, F_2=T) = \frac{P(C=T \;\cap \;F_1=T\;\cap\;F_2=T)}{P(F_1=T\;\cap\;F_2=T)}$$
but I'm not sure where to go from there

Comment: How can you assume that $C, F_1, F_2$ are independent? Note that $P(F_1 = T\mid C=T) \ne P(F_1 = T\mid C=F)$, so $F_1$ and $C$ are dependent.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that F1 and F2 are independent, updated!

Comment: Use Bayes Theorem. You are given the a priori probabilities of $F_1=T$, $F_2=T$, etc under the condition $C=T$. To find $P(F_1=T, F_2=T|C=T)$, etc. use independence of $F_1$ and $F_2$ (indepedence is preserved by conditioning).

Comment: @GReyes Ok that makes sense, but I'm stuck on finding $P(F1=T)$ and $P(F2=T)$ in the denominator

Comment: By the total probability formula, $P(F_1=T)=P(F_1=T|C=F)P(C=F)+P(F_1=T|C=T)P(C=T)$.                                           You know all these quantities, $P(C=F)=1-P(C=T)$. I do not know how to avoid the formula from cutting into two pieces. Hope you understand it.

Comment: @GReyes Oh wow...so straightforward, completely forgot about that...thanks!